# Get the rank of the row given the order in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Let's say I have two tables like the following:

```
user_id
1
2
3

post_id    user_id
1          2
2          3
3          2
```

The first table has all of the user information and the second table is a list of posts from users.

With these table, I want to make a ranking of who post the most posts. To do this, I can use the following sql

```
select user.user_id from user
left join post on user.user_id=post.user_id
order by  count(post.post_id)
```

which will give me

```
user_id
2
3
1
```

, but what if I only want a single user's rank? In other words, I want to write a sql statement that will return what place the user is in given the user_id. For example, I want 1 as output if I have user_id of 2, 2 as the output if I have user_id 3, and 3 as the output if I have user_id 1.

Is this possible, or would I have to select the entire table and do a while loop in php until I hit the user and count the rows above?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for a single user's rank, you pretty much have to calculate the rank of everyone and then pull out the single user.  So, the ranking for all users is:

```
select u.user_id, count(p.post_id), (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
from user u left join 
     post p
     on u.user_id = p.user_id cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
group by u.user_id
order by count(p.post_id) desc;
```

And for one user, use a subquery:

```
select *
from (select u.user_id, count(p.post_id), (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
      from user u left join 
           post p
           on u.user_id = p.user_id cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by count(p.post_id) desc
     ) u
where u.user_id = $USERID;
```

Comment: Isn't this missing a `group by` clause?  Also you need to alias the columns in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user-defined variables` for this:

```
select rnk
from (
    select user.user_id, @rnk:@rnk+1 rnk
    from user
        left join post on user.user_id=post.user_id
        cross join (select @rnk:=0) t
    group by user.user_id
    order by count(post.post_id) desc
) t
where user_id = ?
```

BTW -- I believe your query was missing a `group by` clause.  Added above.

Comment: Oh, yes, mine was missing group by. Thank you for the correction